# Is there a larger interface for older owners?

Tags: screen, app-icons

Does anyone know of a larger visual interface for older owners on android phones?  It seems to me that most programmers haven't experienced over 40 eyesight.  :-)  Much less over 50, 60 etc.

Having an option for larger icons and text throughout the phone would be a fantastic.  I know a slew of over 40 folks who are technically savvy but have to wear reader glasses to see the phone interface well.

Answer (score 2):

I've thought about this as well for my senior parents. There are really only two options:

1. Replace the stock launcher with something like [BIG Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=name.kunes.android.launcher.activity) ($10) or [Large Launcher Senior](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tbeasy.largelauncher) (free). The downside to these is that they feel more childish, and some older tech-savvy users might not appreciate that.
2. - Increase the font size that Android displays text in. Some versions of Android already have an option under `Settings > Accessibility > Large Text` (SIDENOTE: Magnification gestures may also be helpful to some senior users who can remember them). Additionally, [Big Font](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.bfont) (free) offers more granular control over font sizes.
   - Pair that with a third-party launcher, like [Apex](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher) and [Holo Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobint.hololauncher.hd) which allow you to change the icon sizes on both the home screen(s) and the app drawer. Another nice thing is that you can hide apps with these launchers too, so you could hide apps that might not be helpful for the user to see every time they search the drawer.

Answer (score 2):

When my mother first switched to a smart phone I made her a customized launcher with Lightning Launcher. Its free and has tons of customizations. Downfall is that it might take a bit to learn all the features but once you learn its really incredible. You can change icon size, text size, icon rotation, and even set it up with massive fonts so putting on glasses to use the phone isn't always required